# postgresql : **ERROR: path element at position 1 is not an integer:**

Tags: jsonb, postgresql-10

I am trying to update a field value in jsonb column with text value present in another column but getting some syntax errors; not getting any solution.

```
'[
      {
         "Edgeid":10,
         "Weight":100,
         "Active":1,
         "OutgoingVertexid":"",
         "IncomingVertexid":"G",
         "EdgeColor":"Black"
      }
   ]
'
```

so used below code by putting all values OutgoingVertexid & IncomingVertexid value in temp table.

```
UPDATE temp_table 
        SET 
        owner_property = CASE 
                            WHEN owner_outgoing_edge IS NOT NULL 
                                THEN jsonb_set(owner_property, '{OutgoingVertexid}', '""')
                            ELSE NULL END;
                                jsonb_set(owner_property, '{OutgoingVertexid}', ''||owner_incoming_edge::jsonb||'') 
                                END;
```

but getting below error:

**ERROR:  path element at position 1 is not an integer:** "OutgoingVertexid"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Answer to this exact question is published here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/270655